# I can't get puppeteer-core to use the search parameters in the url to get a full list of items from a website by changing the "pageSize" parameter

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am trying to get a list of items from a website with puppeteer-core. 
Here is the code that should print 774 in the console but only returns 24.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

async function test() {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
await page.goto("https://www.liveauctioneers.com/catalog/256884_8-27-22-cameo-cut-glass-art-glass-and-more/?page=1&pageSize=1000", {waitUntil: "networkidle2"});

let pageContent = await page.content()
let dom = new JSDOM(pageContent)
let div = dom.window.document.querySelectorAll("div")
await div.forEach(element => {
    if (element.id == "content") {
        dom = new JSDOM(element.innerHTML)
        div = dom.window.document.querySelectorAll("div")
        div.forEach(element => {
            if (element.className == "App__StyledApp-sc-eiwfgw-0 cHSpyq") {
                dom = new JSDOM(element.innerHTML)
                div = dom.window.document.querySelectorAll("div")
                div.forEach(element => {
                    if (element.id == "main") {
                        dom = new JSDOM(element.innerHTML)
                        div = dom.window.document.querySelectorAll("div")
                        dom = new JSDOM(div[0].innerHTML)
                        div = dom.window.document.querySelectorAll("div")
                        div.forEach(element => {
                            if (element.className == "CatalogPageItems__StyledContainer-sc-y0p083-0 bLuQEb") {
                                dom = new JSDOM(element.innerHTML)
                                div = dom.window.document.querySelectorAll("div")
                                dom = new JSDOM(div[1].innerHTML)
                                div = dom.window.document.querySelectorAll("div")
                                dom = new JSDOM(div[0].innerHTML)
                                div = dom.window.document.querySelectorAll("div")
                                console.log(div.length)
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
})

await browser.close();
}

test()
```

For me this code returns 24 instead of 774. If I load the url "https://www.liveauctioneers.com/catalog/256884_8-27-22-cameo-cut-glass-art-glass-and-more/" into my browser the pageSize defaults to 24.

Comment: I am not convinced that using JSDOM over `page.content()` will give you back the elements you want to collect, especially as you visit a dynamic website. you should use the features of puppeteer to see all the ~770 elements (e.g. `page.evaluate`, `page.$eval/$$eval`). not sure, but maybe you can also replace the `if` conditions simply by using [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) targeting your desired elements.

Comment: Whew, this is way complex. Why are you using JSDOM at all when Puppeteer [has selectors built-in](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#using-a-separate-html-parser-with-puppeteer)? Can you show the data you want? Seems like a probable [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676).

Comment: The short answer to why I'm using JSDOM is I was using it before I discovered Puppeteer which solved a problem that I was having difficulty solving with JSDOM and after a couple of frustrating hours of failing to figure out how to use Puppeteer's selectors I decided to just use what I had already working.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simplify the code to find the number of items. I looked only at how many children the grid has and ended up with this one simple line that gives me the correct result:

```js
...
let pageContent = await page.content();
let dom = new JSDOM(pageContent);

let count = dom.window.document.querySelector(".Grid__ItemGridContainer-sc-1fy9g29-0").childElementCount;

console.log(count);
await browser.close();
...
```

Comment: Thank you this did indeed work although I do want to know why. From my little knowledge it seems that all the information I'm looking for should be in the pageContent variable, regardless of whether I'm using the querySelector function or doing it the way I did ,because in both cases the information was stored with,
let pageContent = await page.content()
let dom = new JSDOM(pageContent)

Comment: Might have something to do with you redefining what `dom` is several times. Or, what I think it is, you are selecting different elements. Try to run puppeteer with `{headless: false}`, log the elements to the console and you can see what you're selecting.

Comment: Well I feel dumb, after double checking it turns out your second educated guess was correct and I wasn't selecting the right elements. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Glad you found it out :)